# If $z=-\dfrac12-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}i$, find the value of $z^4+z^8$.

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z=-\dfrac12-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}i$, find the value of $z^4+z^8$.

I have calculated $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{3}{4}}=1$ and $\tan\varphi=\dfrac{b}{a}=\sqrt3$

I got that $z=\cos\dfrac{4\pi}{3}+i\sin\dfrac{4\pi}{3}$

Are we supposed to write $z$ in trig form, or we can do it directly? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ? **Hint** Start to find the argument of $z$.

Comment: @Surb, is this enough_

Comment: Then you can use De Moivre's. Note that $(-1/2 - i \sqrt3/2)^2 = (1/2 + i \sqrt3/2)^2$ which will simplify your calculations.

Comment: @TobyMak, I didn't quite get that and I am not sure what De Moivre's is. Am I supposed to work with the trig form?

Comment: Yes, trig form is the way to go and you should search up what De Moivre's is (for harder problems). More simply, did you notice that $z$ is a cube root of unity?

Comment: Think about the value of $z^3$ and $z^2+z+1$, which can bring you to result very simply.

Comment: @koki De moivres is $(\cos{x}+i\sin{x})^n=\cos{nx}+i\sin{nx}$

Comment: @koki Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Tell us what you know or what you don't know that seems relevant to the question and we can better help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $z=\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}3\right)+\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}3\right)i$. Therefore\begin{align}z^4&=\cos\left(\frac{16\pi}3\right)+\sin\left(\frac{16\pi}3\right)i\\&=\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}3\right)+\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}3\right)i\\&=z\end{align}and\begin{align}z^8&=(z^4)^2\\&=z^2\\&=\cos\left(\frac{8\pi}3\right)+\sin\left(\frac{8\pi}3\right)i\\&=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)+\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)i\\&=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i,\end{align}and so $z^4+z^8=-1$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can I ask you why $\cos\dfrac{16\pi}{3}=\cos\dfrac{4\pi}{3}$

Comment: Because $\frac{16\pi}3-\frac{4\pi}3=\frac{12\pi}3=4\pi$.

Comment: I am not really sure I see which property of the cosine we're using. Can you clarify it for me? Why are we subtracting $\dfrac{4\pi}{3}$ from $\dfrac{16\pi}{3}$ to get $4\pi$?

Comment: I am using the fact that $\cos$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. Therefore$$\cos\left(\frac{16\pi}3\right)=\cos\left(\frac{16\pi}3-4\pi\right)=\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}3\right).$$

Answer (score 8):

> If $z=- \dfrac {1} {2} - \dfrac {\sqrt{3}} {2} i$, find the value of $z^4+z^8$.

\begin{align}
&z=-\frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt{3}} 2 i. \\
&\Rightarrow z^3-1=0.  \tag A \label A\\
\ \\
&\therefore z^2+z+1=0. \tag B \label B\\
\ \\
&\eqref{A} \Rightarrow z^3=1, z^4+z^8=z+z^2. \\
&\eqref{B} \Rightarrow z^2+z=-1. \\
\ \\
&\therefore z^4+z^8=-1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For $ \ z \ = \ -\frac12 - i·\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}} \ \ , \ $ by binomial expansion or application of DeMoivre's Theorem to its polar form $ \ z \ = \ cis \left(\frac{4 \pi}{3} \right) \ \ , \ $ we can establish that $ \ z^4 \ = \ z \ $ and $ \ z^2 \ = \ -\frac12 + i·\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}} \ = \ \overline{z} \ \ . \ $  We then obtain
$$ z^4 \ + \ z^8 \ \ = \ \ z^4·(z^4 \ + \ 1) \ \ = \ \ z·(z  \ + \ 1) \ \ = \ \ z^2 \ + \ z $$ $$ = \ \ \overline{z} \ + \ z \ \ = \ \ 2·\mathfrak{Re}(z) \ \ = \ \ 2·\left(-\frac12 \right) \ \ = \ \ -1 \ \ .$$