# If $z=\dfrac12+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, find the value of $z^4+z^9$

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $z=\dfrac12+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, find the value of $z^4+z^9$.

I have tried to find the trigonometric form of the complex number $z$. We have $Re(z)=a=\dfrac12$ and $Im(z)=b=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}$. The absolute value of $z$ is $r=|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{\dfrac14+\dfrac34}=1$. The argument of $z$ is $\varphi=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$. So $$z=r(\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi)=\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)$$
Then by De Moivre's formula we can derive $$z^4=\cos\left(\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\right)$$ and $$z^9=\cos\left(\dfrac{9\pi}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\dfrac{9\pi}{3}\right)=\cos\left(3\pi\right)+i\sin\left(3\pi\right)$$

Comment: nearly there - $cos(3\pi)$ is?

Comment: @Paul, I really don't know. The problem is that we have studied the trig functions only from the interval $0$ to $180$ degrees and now we are studying complex numbers and as I can see we need them very much.

Comment: @koki You should have learned about the _period_ of sin and cosine, and the partial-period identities that they satisfy (e.g., what is $\cos(x+\pi)$ in terms of $\cos(x)$?); those are what you need here.

Comment: Overall, this is correct. It **can** be simplified (which is likely expected), but numerically, it is at least correct.

Comment: @Clayton, what exactly can be simplified?

Comment: You asked a very similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4314953/42969, don't those answers help?

Comment: All of the trig. values can be simplified (in the same way that you notice $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i= e^{i\pi/3}$.

Answer (score 2):

As you have found that $z=e^{\pi i/3}$ then $z^3=-1$ and thus
$$
z^4+z^9= z(z^3)+(z^3)^3= -z-1=-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can use the the exponential form:
$$z^4=\left(\dfrac12+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\right)^4=e^{4\cdot\frac{\pi}{3}i}=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$$
And:
$$z^9=\left(\dfrac12+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\right)^9=e^{9\cdot\frac{\pi}{3}}=e^{3\pi}=e^{\pi}=-1$$
So, the value we wanted to compute is:
$$-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$$
Your procedure is right. You have only to express $z^4$ and $z^9$ in algebric form and then sum together.

Comment: @koki: if this answer has been useful, please let me know smashing that +1 and accepted answerd button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your start is good, just sum the two of them to get

$-\frac 32 - \frac{\sqrt{3}} 2 i$

becauase

$cos\left(\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\right) = -\frac 12$

$sin\left(\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\right) = -\frac{\sqrt{3}} 2$

$\cos\left(3\pi\right) = -1$

$\sin\left(3\pi\right) = 0$